# Error When Using Web Service in DLL

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I have got a web service in .net. I've made a windows forms application using it but when I make a DLL and add it as a reference to my project, it doesn't work and throws

> Could not find an endpoint with name "FaturaServiceSoap" and contract "BimsaFaturaService.FaturaServiceSoap" in the service model client configuration section.

app.config in class library project:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FaturaServiceSoap">

        </binding>
        <binding name="FaturaServiceSoap1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="FaturaServiceSoap12">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="FaturaServiceSoap" address="https://efaturatest.edoksis.net/FaturaService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FaturaServiceSoap" contract="BimsaFaturaService.FaturaServiceSoap" />
      <endpoint name="FaturaServiceSoap12" address="https://efaturatest.edoksis.net/FaturaService.asmx" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="FaturaServiceSoap12" contract="BimsaFaturaService.FaturaServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

app.config in winforms app:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 

    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="FaturaServiceSoap">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="FaturaServiceSoap1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="FaturaServiceSoap12">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://efaturatest.edoksis.net/FaturaService.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FaturaServiceSoap"
                contract="ServiceReference1.FaturaServiceSoap" name="FaturaServiceSoap" />
            <endpoint address="https://efaturatest.edoksis.net/FaturaService.asmx"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="FaturaServiceSoap12"
                contract="ServiceReference1.FaturaServiceSoap" name="FaturaServiceSoap12" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

What should I do? Thanks for help!

Comment: You should add the endpoint configuration to the app.config of the project that uses the class library. That's because the project won't use the app.config of the class library.

Answer (score 0):

Move the configuration settings from the class library to the app.config since their values are otherwise overwritten.